# NSDateFormatter return nil on 2 different input which in same format?

Tags: objective-c, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am newbie of objective-c and i got this crazy problem…

for low precision test case:

> dateString = @"2010-05-25 11:05:21", conversion success.
>
> dateString = @"2010-03-01 15:54:36", conversion fail.

for high precision test case:

> dateString = @"2010-05-25 11:05:21.937113", conversion success.
>
> dateString = @"2010-03-01 15:54:36.937113", conversion fail.

below is my code:

```
// Date formatter
 NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
 [dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS"];
 [dateFormatter setLocale:locale];

NSDateFormatter *lowPrecisionDateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[lowPrecisionDateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[lowPrecisionDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
[lowPrecisionDateFormatter setLocale:locale];

// try high precision first, if fail, then go ahead to low precision. 
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
if(!date){
  date = [lowPrecisionDateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a guess, but I think it has to do with using a 24-hour day format rather than AM and PM. I believe if you use HH rather than hh in your `setDateFormat` string that it should work.

Edit:

Actually, I'm pretty confident that this is it after looking at [this blog posting](http://www.stepcase.com/blog/2008/12/02/format-string-for-the-iphone-nsdateformatter/).